# Selection of sigma variable for gaussian function

Tags: filtering, fft

I am new to signal processing and would like to apply low pass filter using fft.
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814547/matlab-low-pass-filter-using-fft/) which answers my question. While using it, I have one question:
given that my cutoff frequency is 3500Hz and sampling rate is 25600Hz,
what will be the value of `sigma` to use while generating Gaussian curve, as given by code from [eigenchris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3777428/eigenchris)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816314/2994596) below?

```
gauss = zeros(size(Y));    
sigma = 8;                           % just a guess for a range of 20

gauss(1:r+1) = exp(-(1:r+1).^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));  % +ve frequencies
gauss(end-r+1:end) = fliplr(gauss(2:r+1));           % -ve frequencies
y_gauss = ifft(Y.*gauss,1024);
```

**Below is function code I am using:**

```
clf; clc;
Fs    = 25600;
file   = '01cKhaitan181015M4_Opp_LeftS1H8_a.dat';
signal = dlmread(file); % read file from specified location
signal = signal - mean(signal);

N      = size(signal, 1);
time   = 1000*(0 : N-1)/Fs;    % in msec
freq   = (-Fs/2 : Fs/N : Fs/2-Fs/N)';

Y = fft(signal, 1024);

r = 141; % range of frequencies we want to preserve

gauss = zeros(size(Y));
sigma = 119.75; 
gauss(1:r+1) = exp(-(1:r+1).^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));  % +ve frequencies
gauss(end-r+1:end) = fliplr(gauss(2:r+1));           % -ve frequencies
y_gauss = ifft(Y.*gauss,1024);

hold on;
plot(time, signal, 'k'); plot(time, abs(y_gauss), 'c');
legend('signal', 'gaussian', 'Location', 'southwest')
hold off;
```

**Below is link of data file**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/edb8g43j4a54jvq/01cKhaitan181015M4_Opp_LeftS1H8_a.dat?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The cutoff frequency is defined as the frequency where the attenuation is `0.5` or ~6dB. You already know the desired cutoff frequency to be 3500Hz. The next step would be to get the corresponding index with:

```
cutoff_frequency = 3500;
sampling_rate = 25600;
cutoff_index = 1 + cutoff_frequency/sampling_rate * length(Y);
```

At that `cutoff_index` you would want to have the desired 0.5 attenuation. Solving for `sigma` which yields an attenuation of 0.5 at the `cutoff_index` in your Gaussian formula:

```
%% Derivation of sigma value
% 0.5 = exp(-cutoff_index^2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));
% log(0.5) = -cutoff_index^2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));
% sigma^2 = -cutoff_index^2 / (2 * log(0.5));
% sigma^2 = cutoff_index^2 / (2 * log(2));
```

yielding:

```
sigma = cutoff_index / sqrt(2 * log(2));
```

So, if for example `length(Y)` is 1024, you would get

```
sigma = (3500/25600 * 1024) / sqrt(2 * log(2)); % approx. 119.75
```

Comment: While using calculated sigma, filter data plot is too much different than raw plot. Any problem or my understanding? To check, I am adding the matlab function and data file.

Comment: A few things: **1)** `fliplr` would not reverse the sequence if it's argument is a column vector; you could use `gauss(r+1:-1:2)` which works regardless of whether you have a row or column vector instead of `fliplr(gauss(2:r+1))` . **2)** If you are going to compare time signals, you should probably be plotting `y_gauss` instead of `abs(y_gauss)`. **3)** You'd have slightly less frequency leakage if you increased `r` a bit more.

Comment: Filter time plot matches with signal, mistake as pointed in point 2 (using abs()). Suggestion 3 -> by changing r, does sigma will impact? Other words, sigma and r are related?

Comment: `r` controls the number of non-zero points in the frequency domain. For a non-gaussian lowpass as was done in the other post you used, `r` controlled the cutoff directly. In your case, the gaussian shape provides a gradual attenuation past the cutoff frequency, so you might as well let the shape take care of the out-of-band attenuation by making `r` as large as possible (which can be up to `length(Y)/2+1`). Otherwise, if you choose to keep `r` smaller than the maximum possible, you'd have to keep it larger than the `cutoff_index`. Other than that `r` and `sigma` are pretty much independent.